# How to configure Kafka key SERIALIZER , for the cases where sometimes key is long and other times key is String?

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have kafka producer configuration , till this time i am sending key as String type and configured key SERIALIZER like below ,

```
configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ObjectSerializer.class.getName());
```

but we got one requirement that some time key might be long also , so without creating another producer config is there anyway we can config above thing as like ObjectSerializer ? anything present like that ?

**My spring-kafka version is 2.1 , so i cannot use DelegatingSerializer and i cannot upgrade the version in the project .**

Update 1:

I created custom Serializer like below and configured it as my key Serializer , but after publishing the message with some long value as key and when i saw the key it contains some garbage symbols , can anyone correct the below code if anything wrong in it .

```
import org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Map;

public class LongStringSerializer implements Serializer<Object> {

    private String encoding = "UTF8";

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {
        String propertyName = isKey ? "key.serializer.encoding" : "value.serializer.encoding";
        Object encodingValue = configs.get(propertyName);
        if (encodingValue == null)
            encodingValue = configs.get("serializer.encoding");
        if (encodingValue != null && encodingValue instanceof String)
            encoding = (String) encodingValue;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(String topic, Object data) {
        if (data == null)
            return null;

        if (data instanceof Long) {
            return serialize(Long.parseLong(data.toString()));
        }

        if (data instanceof String) {
            return serializeStringData((String) data);
        }
        return new byte[0];
    }

    private byte[] serializeStringData(String data) {
        try {
            return data.getBytes(encoding);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            throw new SerializationException("Error when serializing string to byte[] due to unsupported encoding " + encoding);
        }
    }

    private byte[] serialize(Long data) {
        if (data == null)
            return null;

        return new byte[] {
                (byte) (data >>> 56),
                (byte) (data >>> 48),
                (byte) (data >>> 40),
                (byte) (data >>> 32),
                (byte) (data >>> 24),
                (byte) (data >>> 16),
                (byte) (data >>> 8),
                data.byteValue()
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        // nothing to do
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [Delegating Serializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#delegating-serialization).

> Version 2.3 introduced the DelegatingSerializer and DelegatingDeserializer, which allow producing and consuming records with different key and/or value types. Producers must set a header DelegatingSerializer.SERIALIZATION_SELECTOR to a selector value that is used to select which serializer to use; if a match is not found, an IllegalStateException is thrown.

It requires a header to tell it which serializer to use, but you could write a simpler version that simply looks at the key type.

(I think I will enhance the `DelegatingSerializer` to do that).

**Another alternative is to use different producers for each.**

With version 2.5, you can override producer factory properties on the `KafkaTemplate`:

```java
    /**
     * Create an instance using the supplied producer factory and properties, with
     * autoFlush false. If the configOverrides is not null or empty, a new
     * {@link DefaultKafkaProducerFactory} will be created with merged producer properties
     * with the overrides being applied after the supplied factory's properties.
     * @param producerFactory the producer factory.
     * @param configOverrides producer configuration properties to override.
     * @since 2.5
     */
    public KafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<K, V> producerFactory, @Nullable Map<String, Object> configOverrides) {
```

So simply define a different `KafkaTemplate` for each type.

With older versions you would need two producer factories with different configurations.

Comment: The delegating serializer now handles this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/pull/1491